# AWS API gateway path rather than query string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am creating an API using AWS API Gateway and am currently using query strings to pass values into my lambda functions. This results in the URLs being structured like so:

```
users/user?user_id='test123'
```

What I would like to do is uses a path to pas in values rather than query strings. For example:

```
users/user/id/test123
```

I have looked at mapping templates and understand they are used to convert the data into the format for the function, but I am not sure how I can use a path and then map it into the lambda function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a resource with a variable component path like this:

```
/users/user/id/{userid}
```

Then you'd use a mapping template to pass the userid value to the Lambda function in the body of the request:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  "userId" : "$input.params('userid')"
}
```

Note that Lambda functions only accept parameters in the body, not query string.